# How can you launch a windows 10 app from command line?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe

Elsewhere on the internet, there is advice that the 'best' way to launch a "Windows 10 app" aka UWP app is via a new explorer.exe process, using the 'shell:' protocol, (If it hasn't registered it's own protocol)

```
param([string]$AppName)

$Path="shell:appsfolder\"+(Get-AppXPackage | where{$_.Name -match "$AppName"} | select -expandproperty packagefamilyname)+"!App"

return $Path
```

however, calling this script results in

```
PS C:\Users\RyanLeach\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts> $ShareX = ./findapp.ps1 ShareX

PS C:\Users\RyanLeach\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts> $ShareX
shell:appsfolder\19568ShareX.ShareX_egrzcvs15399j!App

PS C:\Users\RyanLeach\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts> Start-Process -FilePath $ShareX
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process -FilePath $ShareX
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

So how can you launch a Store app (Desktop or UWP) via command-line / PowerShell, passing arguments?

Comment: Why couldn't it be as simple as AppX -App ShareX -ArgumentList {}

Comment: Type `reg query  HKCR /s /f URL:*`. This is what you type.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "explorer.exe"  "shell:appsFolder\19568ShareX.ShareX_egrzcvs15399j!App"
```

Comment: comments elsewhere suggests this leaves a bunch of explorer.exe's hanging around.

Comment: Yes, yes it does, but you need to capture the process Id of the one you started and stop that at the end of the process/call.

Comment: If your answer dealt with that, I'd accept.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach, you got an answer for what you've asked, so you should have accepted it. After all, as you already know PS, `help Start-Process` will lead you to know that a Process object (with an **Id**) is its output.

Comment: Disagree, it has side effects that arn't dealt with, nor does it explain what was wrong in the script I had. Please read up on what an accepted answer means: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer